# Firebase - How to update a list of data?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an Android chat application using Firebase and I would like to set all unseen messages to "seen".

Under Messages: The first node is the sender id, the second node is the receiver id, the third nodes are the message ids.

I want to set all messages, where the field "seen" has the value "false", set to "true".

The Firebase reference for the list would be:

```
DatabaseReference userMessages = mRootRef.child("Messages").child(mCurrentUser.getUid()).child(mPartnerID);
```

[image: messages data structure on firebase]

[Checking the Firebase docs about lists of data they only mention inserting new data into lists and reading lists, but not updating.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data)

Question: How can I set all entries with `"seen": false` set to `"seen": true`?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference userMessages = mRootRef.child("Messages").child(mCurrentUser.getUid()).child(mPartnerID);
Query query = query.orderByChild("seen").equalsTo(false);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            ds.child("seen").getRef().setValue(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to update is to use `updateChildren()`:

```
DatabaseReference userMessages = mRootRef.child("Messages").child(mCurrentUser.getUid()).child(mPartnerID);

userMessages.orderByChild("seen").equalTo(false).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            String key=datas.getKey();
            Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
            childUpdates.put(key+"/seen/", true);
            userMessages.updateChildren(childUpdates);
     }
  }

 @Override
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Here you add the reference at the `mPartnerID`, then add a query to be able to retrieve all the keys that have `seen:false` as a child, and using `updateChildren()` you will be able to update the `seen` field.

Check here for more info:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields